# Demean R data.table: list of columns

Tags: r, data.table

I want to demean a whole `data.table` object (or just a list of many columns of it) by groups.

Here's my approach so far:

```
setkey(myDt, groupid)
for (col in colnames(wagesOfFired)){
   myDt[, paste(col, 'demeaned', sep='.') := col - mean(col), with=FALSE]
}
```

which gives

```
Error in col - mean(col) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Here's some sample data. In this simple case, there's only two columns, but I typically have so many columns such that I want to iterate over a list

```
            y  groupid    x
 1:   3.46000 51557094   97
 2: 111.60000 51557133   25
 3:  29.36000 51557133   23
 4:  96.38000 51557133    9
 5:  65.22000 51557193   32
 6:  66.05891 51557328   10
 7:   9.74000 51557328  180
 8:  61.59000 51557328   18
 9:   9.99000 51557328   18
10:  89.68000 51557420  447
11: 129.24436 51557429   15
12:   3.46000 51557638 3943
13: 117.36000 51557642   11
14:   9.51000 51557653   83
15:  68.16000 51557653  518
16:  96.38000 51557653   14
17:   9.53000 51557678   18
18:   7.96000 51557801  266
19:  51.88000 51557801   49
20:  10.70000 51558040 1034
```

Comment: Maybe something like `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(groupid) %>% mutate_each(funs(. - mean(.)))` ?

Comment: `myDt[, lapply(.SD, function(x)x - mean(x)), by=groupid]`

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `col` is a string, so `col-mean(col)` cannot be computed.

```
myNames <- names(myDt)
myDt[,paste(myNames,"demeaned",sep="."):=
  lapply(.SD,function(x)x-mean(x)),
by=groupid,.SDcols=myNames]
```

*Comments:*

- You don't need to set a key.
- It's in one operation because using `[` repeatedly can be slow.
- You can change `myNames` to some subset of the column names.